# Move from intelliji Ultimate to Community edition issue with decompiled classes

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have had to stop using the Inteliji Ultimate edition so I have moved to the community edition. I have a project that I am working on which was working fine in ultimate (yesterday) but when I open it up in the community edition it is not opening up the source code it is opening the files up as decompiled class files and placing the following message at top of each class

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//
```

The program is a spring boot program , using Maven and also Thymeleaf. I can open it up in Netbeans but then I get dependency errors

Any ideas?

Comment: Spring is supported in Ultimate edition only: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html. So, probably, project structure is not detected proprly and decompiled version is used instead of actual sources.

Comment: thank you, I was banging my head against a brick wall trying to work it out! Looks like I will need to try another IDE